# Smarty - can't insert variable content into javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, smarty

I need to insert content of variable with Smarty syntax into javascript, like below. The script is checking if page is opened from validation link in email sent to customer.

```
{literal}
<script>
   if ((document.URL).indexOf("validation") > -1) {      

      $('.loginForm').append( 
          "<p class='middleWarningTextP loginMessage'>{/literal}{$VALIDATION_NOTICE->getMessage()}{literal}</p>");

   }
</script>
{/literal}
```

Problem is, that this works only if javascript condition is true, otherwise page is loaded wrong: between `<header>` and `</header>` tag is nothing! and therefore css style is not loaded. I don't understand it, is there a way to repair it?

Comment: Smarty 2 or Smarty 3?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `{literal}` tags (as some answers suggest). They are properly used. There is no need to remove them. I would [escape for Javascript](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl) the value returned by `$VALIDATION_NOTICE->getMessage()` (except if it doesn't come already escaped which is not the correct behaviour, btw). Other than that, check (or show) your PHP code because this is where the problem is.

Comment: I tryed my original code accompanied by {$VALIDATION_NOTICE->getMessage()|escape:'javascript'}, but the same error occured.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the {literal} tags. Smarty does not execute statements within these tags [More info](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal). But then, if use curly braces inside your javascript, you need to write your statements on multiple lines:

```
var test = {
    value: 'test'
}
```

Comment: I dont understand. What should I type exactly in my case?

Comment: Your code should look like this:

`<script>
   if ((document.URL).indexOf("validation") > -1) {      

      $('.loginForm').append( 
          "<p class='middleWarningTextP loginMessage'>{$VALIDATION_NOTICE->getMessage()}</p>");

   }`
</script>

Comment: this code doesn't work, causing the same error even if curly braces or are at new lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Smarty 3

```
<script>
   if ((document.URL).indexOf("validation") > -1) {      

      $('.loginForm').append( 
          "<p class='middleWarningTextP loginMessage'>{$VALIDATION_NOTICE->getMessage()}{literal}</p>");

   }
</script>
```

That is, simply remove the {literal} tags

If you're using Smarty 2 instead, i think it's something like this

```
<script>
   if ((document.URL).indexOf("validation") > -1) {ldelim}      

      $('.loginForm').append( 
          "<p class='middleWarningTextP loginMessage'>{$VALIDATION_NOTICE->getMessage()}</p>");

   {rdelim}
</script>
```

Comment: next time, provide better informations, do some personal research and try on your own a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not with {literals} tags or syntax. Problem was that $VALIDATION_NOTICE->getMessage() variable was not set in some cases. Therefore I added this condition:

```
{if !is_array($VALIDATION_NOTICE) and $VALIDATION_NOTICE}{$VALIDATION_NOTICE->getMessage()}{/if}
```

and now it works right.